# jhipster principal.service.js not working correct for hasAuthority. Need to disable menus based

Tags: angularjs, rest, file-permissions, jhipster, principal

We are using jHipster.  I am new to this.

When trying to access another method hasPermission, it is always returning false before and hence we are unable to disable the menu.  In authority, we are passing values like 'Company' and this checks internally with a userPermission Object to see if the user has 'Read' access.  The user does have the access, but the code always returns false and hence the menu is always disabled.  Am I making something wrong here ?  Here is the complete code

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('icmApp')
        .factory('Principal', Principal);

    Principal.$inject = ['$q', 'Account'];

    function Principal ($q, Account) {
        var _identity,
           _authenticated = false;

        var _authenticated = false;


        var service = {
            authenticate: authenticate,
            hasAnyAuthority: hasAnyAuthority,
            hasAuthority: hasAuthority,
            identity: identity,
            isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
            isIdentityResolved: isIdentityResolved,
            hasPermission: hasPermission
        };

        return service;

        function authenticate (identity) {
            _identity = identity;
            _authenticated = identity !== null;

        }

        function hasAnyAuthority (authorities) {
            if (!_authenticated || !_identity || !_identity.authorities) {
                  return false;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < authorities.length; i++) {
                if (_identity.authorities.indexOf(authorities[i]) !== -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        function hasAuthority (authority) {
            if (!_authenticated) {
                return $q.when(false);
            }

            var bPerm= hasPermission(authority);
            if(bPerm==true)
                {
                    alert("Permission is available");
                return true;
                }else
                    {
                    alert("Permission is NOT available");
                    return false;
                }

           /*return then(function(_id) {
                return _id.authorities && _id.authorities.indexOf(authority) !== -1;
            },function(){
                return false;
            });*/
        }

        function identity (force) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if (force === true) {
                _identity = undefined;
            }


            // check and see if we have retrieved the identity data from the server.
            // if we have, reuse it by immediately resolving
            if (angular.isDefined(_identity)) {
                deferred.resolve(_identity);

                return deferred.promise;
            }

            // retrieve the identity data from the server, update the identity object, and then resolve.
            Account.get().$promise
                .then(getAccountThen)
                .catch(getAccountCatch);

            return deferred.promise;

            function getAccountThen (account) {
                _identity = account.data;
                _authenticated = true;
                deferred.resolve(_identity);
            }

            function getAccountCatch () {
                _identity = null;
                _authenticated = false;
                deferred.resolve(_identity);
            }
        }

        function isAuthenticated () {
            return _authenticated;
        }

        function isIdentityResolved () {
            return angular.isDefined(_identity);
        }

        function hasPermission(authority){

            var userPermission;
            var bPermission=false;

            //alert("Calling has Permission");
            Account.getAllPermissions(function onSuccess(data) {
                userPermission=data;

                if(userPermission){
                    //alert("User Permission is "+ userPermission);
                     for(var i=0; i< userPermission.length; i++)
                     {
                         if((userPermission[i].object_name==authority)&& ((userPermission[i].read_access==true) || (userPermission[i].create_access==true)) )
                             {
                                bPermission= true;
                                break;

                             }
                     }
                }
            });

            return bPermission;
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: Read about how to use Promise. You are reading a value before your promise gets resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  My team member introduced the promise statement and it does seem to get the desired result.